# touch events not firing on anchor with no href

Tags: javascript, html, ios

Consider the following:

```
<a class="addThing">link</a>

$(document).on('click','.addThing',function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

On my iPhone I couldn't get a click event to fire on this anchor until I added `href="javascript:"` to the anchor. The anchor was added to the DOM after the page load. I'm able to recreate this by using JS to add an anchor to the DOM and confirmed it doesn't register the click, but if I added it on page load it does.

This suggests that the phone/browser/OS is somehow treating the elements differently if loaded to the DOM via javascript, but it's the same HTML.

I have a few questions:

1. Why does the href need to be there for the click event to fire.
2. Is there another method to get the event to register? (I was thinking something to do with tab index or something like that.)
3. Is this specific to OS/Device/Browser/Platform or is this something working as it should per W3C documentation?
4. Is `javascript:` the same as `javascript:void(0)`. I came across the `void(0)` thing while researching this and I've always just done `javascript:`.

**EDIT**

Per http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/10/click_event_del_1.html
Answer to 1,2 & 3 apparently because the `href` in turn adds the CSS styling of `cursor: pointer` it makes it magically work. I don't have an android device to test.

Answer to #4 is apparently, it's 2016. Not sure what that means.

Comment: an `<a>` doesn't become clickable unless it has an href. e.g. `<a name="foo">Bar</a>` is just a named anchor. it's a TARGET of clicks, not a source of clicks.

Comment: It's 2016, don't use *any* form of `javascript:`.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works if it's added with the page instead of with Javascript.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara what is better? You need something in there, as I just found out.

Comment: @Leeish If anything, use `href="#"` and `preventDefault`. But really, why do you have an `a` tag without a `href`? What's the point of having an `a` tag with no link? Are you looking for `button`?

Comment: Old habits die hard my friend. In this particular case it's a font-glyph. So I could just use the glyph itself probably. Currently swapping HTML of the anchor but I could probably just as easily toggle classes for a similar if not the same effect, assuming the element would accept clicks, which now I wonder if it would, as the anchor doesn't after it's added to the DOM.

Comment: Just found this and tested it, which blew my mind: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/10/click_event_del_1.html I created an empty glyph using font-awesome, added the class and listened for the event. Nothing, Added the `style="cursor: pointer;"` and it magically worked. Sorry, but wtf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//use following css for a 

a {cursor:pointer;}
```